# Adding pagination links to onclick change image

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I have a javascript that changes the image scr when you click on the image and it will cycle through. I want to add pagination links to this script. I want a Previous & Next text link but I don't know how to make the Previous link to go back a image and the Next link to go to the next image.

Here's the live demo http://jsfiddle.net/08p52h59/3/

html:

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="nav">
            <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/tL6nW.gif"></a>
            <a href="http://meta.stackoverflow.com/"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/BfZ5f.gif"></a>
            <a href="http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/mR7wo.gif"></a>       
   </div>
</div>
<div id="d"></div>
```

javascript:

```
$(function() {

    var $images = $("#container > .nav > a").clone();  

    var $length = $images.length;
    var $imgShow = 0;

    $("#container > .nav").html( $("#container > .nav > a:first") ); 

    $("#container > .nav > a:first").click(function(event) { 

        $(this).children().attr("src", 
                        $("img", $images).eq(++$imgShow % $length).attr("src") );

        $("#container > .nav > a:last").attr("href", $($images).eq($imgShow % $length).attr("href"));

        event.preventDefault();

    });
});
```

Can anyone tell me how to add these pagination links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was playing around with something similar and thought I'd share it in case it's of any use to you, different ideas on how to do it.

```js
/* set first image in frame from shoebox on document.ready */
$(function() {
  var leadOff = $('shoebox img:first-child').attr('source');
 $('.picture').attr({'src' : leadOff, 'imageposition' : '1'});
});
/* load next image from shoebox (click on image and/or next button) */
$('pictureframe, buttonright').click(function() {
  var imageTally = $('shoebox img').length;
 var imagePosition = $('.picture').attr('imageposition');
  var plusOne = parseInt(imagePosition) + 1;
  var nextUp = $('shoebox img:nth-child(' + plusOne + ')').attr('source');
  if (imagePosition == imageTally) {
    var leadOff = $('shoebox img:first-child').attr('source');
    $('.picture').attr({'src' : leadOff, 'imageposition' : '1'});
  } else {
    $('.picture').attr({'src' : nextUp, 'imageposition' : plusOne});
  }
});
/* load previous image from shoebox (click on prev button) */
$('buttonleft').click(function() {
  var imageTally = $('shoebox img').length;
 var imagePosition = $('.picture').attr('imageposition');
  var minusOne = parseInt(imagePosition) - 1;
  var nextUp = $('shoebox img:nth-child(' + minusOne + ')').attr('source');
  if (imagePosition == '1') {
    var lastPic = $('shoebox img:last-child').attr('source');
    $('.picture').attr({'src' : lastPic, 'imageposition' : imageTally});
  } else {
    $('.picture').attr({'src' : nextUp, 'imageposition' : minusOne});
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
wall {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 6px;
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 20%, 1);
}
pictureframe {
  display: flex;
  padding: 6px;
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 40%, 1);
}
pictureframe img {
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
buttonswrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
buttonleft, buttonright {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 6px;
  color: hsla(40, 20%, 70%, 1);
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 40%, 1);
  cursor: pointer;
}
buttonleft:hover, buttonright:hover {
  background-color: hsla(50, 50%, 40%, 1);
}
shoebox {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<wall>
  <pictureframe>
    <img class="picture" src="">
  </pictureframe>
  <buttonswrapper>
    <buttonleft>prev</buttonleft>
    <buttonright>next</buttonright>
  </buttonswrapper>
</wall>
<shoebox>
  <!-- prevent loading all images by changing src to source -->
  <img source="http://i.imgur.com/tL6nW.gif">
  <img source="http://i.imgur.com/BfZ5f.gif">
  <img source="http://i.imgur.com/mR7wo.gif">  
</shoebox>
```

**fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/bjw9rpo0/8/

Let me know if annotations are needed and if you need the href's I have some ideas for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could add *data-id=NUMBER* param and get `$(this).attr('data-id')` when it's clicked and showing +1 (next) or -1 (previous). Current showed image need a class too to know where's the pointer. Check when you'll go over to get the first / last one.

*Full example*

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="nav">
            <a class="current" data-id="1" href="http://stackoverflow.com/"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/tL6nW.gif"></a>
            <a data-id="2" href="http://meta.stackoverflow.com/"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/BfZ5f.gif"></a>
            <a data-id="3" href="http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/mR7wo.gif"></a>       
   </div>
</div>
<div id="d">
  <a class="prev" href="">Prev</a>
  <a class="next" href="">Next</a></div>
```

**CSS**

```
a img {
  display: none;
}

a.current img {
  display: block;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {

    $("a").click(function(event) { 

        event.preventDefault();

        var pointer = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var alength = $('.nav a').length;

        if ( !$(this).hasClass('current') ) {
          var pointer = $('a.current').attr('data-id');
          $('a.current').removeClass('current');
        }

        if ($(this).hasClass('prev')){
          $('a.current').removeClass('current');
          pointer--;
          if (pointer < 1) { pointer = alength; }

        } else {
          $(this).removeClass('current');

          pointer++;
          if (pointer > alength) { pointer = 1; }
        }


        $('a[data-id="'+pointer+'"]').addClass('current'); 

    });
});
```

**Codepen**: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/AXGGPJ?editors=1011